# Facing problem live booting

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, 20.04

I can't live boot this version with Rufus. The pc doesn't boot even after changing boot priority from BIOS. The computer just boots as Windows. 
Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It doesn't boot" doesn't really tell us anything useful. Please edit your question to tell us what it *does* do during the boot. Boot includes a series of screens, flickers, and messages that you can describe. A clear video of the failed boot from poweron all the way to failure would really help a lot.

Comment: The computer takes boot as Windows.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot List just about every reason a Bootable USB doesn't boot.

Comment: Did you try to go to boot options (F12 during POST) and boot from there? Some PCs don't boot USBs automatically.

Comment: Yeah,I tried that